# What is the meaning of integral structure and generic fibre？

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

In Peter Scholze's *perfectoid spaces*, *Almost mathematics*, I have difficulty understanding the sequence of localization functors

$$
K^{\circ}-\textrm{mod}\rightarrow K^{\circ}-\textrm{mod}/(\mathfrak{m}-\textrm{torsion})\rightarrow K^{\circ}-\textrm{mod}/(p-\textrm{power torsion}),
$$
which says that it is the functor of passing from an integral structure to its generic fibre.

Here are my questions: What do ''integral structure'' and ''generic fibre'' mean in this context? Why $K^{\circ}-\textrm{mod}/(\mathfrak{m}-\textrm{torsion})\rightarrow K^{\circ}-\textrm{mod}/(p-\textrm{power torsion})$ is a localization functor? And why $K^{\circ}-\textrm{mod}/(p-\textrm{power torsion})$ is equivalent to $K-\textrm{mod}$?

Comment: For the ''generic fibre'', I have been told that it is related to Raynaud's theory of formal-rigid geometry, but I still can't find something useful.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the reference or provide a link? A cursory Google search seems to produce no results with that exact wording. In general, it might be a good idea to explain a bit the notations.

Comment: @ToneyLeung It just means that it's basically the same thing as tensoring with $K$. There are certainly better references for this, but as I am on my phone I will provide the one I know off-hand. See 3.A of this: http://achinger.impan.pl/rigid/notes.pdf

Comment: @Mindlack: Well, $K$ is a fixed perfectoid field. And $K^{\circ}$ is its valuation ring. $K^{\circ}$-mod is the category of $K^{\circ}$-modules. You could find this in Scholze's paper.

Comment: @Alex Youcis: I have been told that this is equivalent to inverting $p$, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: @Toney Leung: I apologize for insisting so much, but I still cannot find a paper by Scholze with this exact title. Could you please provide a link or elaborate on the reference (was this published? if so, where?)?

Comment: @Mindlack: It's OK! https://www.ihes.fr/~abbes/CAGA/PerfectoidSpaces.pdf

Comment: Okay. You’re speaking of the sequence at the beginning of the paragraph “Almost mathematics”, right? But its last term isn’t the $K^{\circ}$-modules modulo $p^{\infty}$-torsion, but directly the $K$-modules. Note, in general, that the $p^{\infty}$-torsion is the kernel of $- \rightarrow - \otimes_{K^{\circ}} K$. If you consider a reasonable enough algebraic structure $X$ over the spectrum of $K^{\circ}$ ($X$ can be, say, a scheme, or a quasicoherent module), then tensoring its global sections with $K$ corresponds to pulling back the generic fiber of the spectrum of $K^{\circ}$.